# python scripts to show perforce changelists

Tags: python, cmd, perforce

when i input these scripts, the result is 0.
i want it to help me show yesterday's submitted changelists, if yesterday is weekends,skip.
it runs in python 3.7
is it grammar mistakes? i don't know how to correct it

```
import os
import datetime
today=datetime.datetime.now() 
yesterday=today-datetime.timedelta(days=1)
twodayago=today-datetime.timedelta(days=2)
threedayago=today-datetime.timedelta(days=3)
if today.weekday()<5:
  message_1=today.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
  message_2=yesterday.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
os.system("p4 changes -s submitted -t //depot2/...message_2,message_1")
elif today.weekday()==5: 
 twodayago.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')  
else:
 threedayago.strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
os.system("pause")    
os.system("pause")    
os.system("pause")
```

it should show the changelists between yesterday and today

Comment: I think you need to use the **values** of the variables `message_2` and `message_1` in your `p4 changes` command.

Comment: Can you put it more clearly?

Comment: how to modify it?

Comment: hello, guy, i have solved the issue, the method os.system only return '0' or '1'

Comment: so i use os.popen(), it returns the output value.